# SQL design for a navigation menu with one of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, normalization

I have navigation menus which have links **either** to an external url, or to a local page identified by the pages PK `pages_id`.

To implement, I created the following tables.

`pages` stores the HTML for the center part in each page.

`menus` stores the name of the menu.

`pages_has_menus` adds the menu to the page, and specified whether it is a main menu, sub menu, etc as specified by `menu_types`.

`menus_has_pages` specifies the actual items in the menu.

How can I ensure that `menus_has_pages` doesn't contain both a `pages_id` and a `external_url`, and also always contains one or the other?

Should the schema be changed by adding addition tables for each scenario?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `sites_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `html` TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_pages_sites_idx` (`sites_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pages_sites`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sites_id`)
    REFERENCES `sites` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menu_types` (
  `type` CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`type`))
ENGINE = InnoDB; 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menus` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `sites_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_menus_sites1_idx` (`sites_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_menus_sites1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sites_id`)
    REFERENCES `sites` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages_has_menus` (
  `pages_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `menus_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `menu_types_type` CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pages_id`, `menus_id`),
  INDEX `fk_pages_has_menus_menus1_idx` (`menus_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_pages_has_menus_pages1_idx` (`pages_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_pages_has_menus_menu_types1_idx` (`menu_types_type` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `unique_menu` (`pages_id` ASC, `menu_types_type` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pages_has_menus_pages1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pages_id`)
    REFERENCES `pages` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pages_has_menus_menus1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`menus_id`)
    REFERENCES `menus` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pages_has_menus_menu_types1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`menu_types_type`)
    REFERENCES `menu_types` (`type`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menus_has_pages` (
  `menus_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `pages_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `external_url` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `order` TINYINT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `new_window` TINYINT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`menus_id`, `pages_id`),
  INDEX `fk_menus_has_pages_pages1_idx` (`pages_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_menus_has_pages_menus1_idx` (`menus_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_menus_has_pages_menus1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`menus_id`)
    REFERENCES `menus` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_menus_has_pages_pages1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pages_id`)
    REFERENCES `pages` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Please let me know why the down-vote.  Should I post this question on a different stack forum?  Anything which you feel should be reworded?

Comment: I like the setup and the FKs. It would be nice to see the existing schema for the other 2 tables. The problem is using your FK with nulls. Plus your real PK is a composite, and not as you described. 

The other tables plus descriptions of use. Otherwise no one can fairly answer this

Comment: @DrewPierce  I added the other two tables.  If it wasn't for the `external_url`, then the composite key makes sense.  Agree how I have it is suspect.

Comment: Why so many nulls? Why no autoincs (not that they are necessary). Can you briefly add language about what the tables are meant for (as in 2 or 3 sentences each).

Comment: @DrewPierce  The nulls are just temporary.  I've added the other tables and a description.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would use two tables instead of yours:

- one with:

  `pages_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
- and one with :

  `external_url` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

And use 'UNION' when you need to merge two 'SELECT' queries.

Comment: Thanks p1erstef.  I was actually thinking of three tables.  A super menu table with a 1-to-1 to both child_pages table and child_external_url table.  Not sure, however...

Comment: @DrewPierce  What other problems?

Comment: You can also keep your one table and use triggers "BEFORE INSERT" and "BEFORE UPDATE" to make sure your constraints are applied.